# Every 10 years the population of a city is five-fourths of what it was 10 years before.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-numbers

I am working through **Serge Lang's** "Basic mathematics", currently on **chapter 1**, Section 5 question 21.

The part that troubles me is, when I asked someone I know how to solve this, they suggested using **logarithm's**, except in Lang's book, **logarithm's** are not until Chapter 13.

So obviously another way exists which I can't figure out.

What would be the best way to solve this assuming one **hasn't yet learned log's**?

Question:

**Every 10 years the population of a city is five-fourths of what it was 10 years before.**

A) How many years does it take before the population doubles?

B) Before it triples?

Comment: Hint: Note that $5/4 \approx \sqrt[3]2$.

Comment: Thank's for the tip, still have no idea where to start though, thought about it for a while.

I realize you can choose any population. On previous question's, I modeled the previous similar questions using the formula A=Ao(1-r)^t/p

Comment: My *guess* is that Lang is not looking for an exact solution, but an estimate.  If you really have no idea how to start, then why don't you try calculating the population of the city after 10, 20, 30, 40, … years, and seeing if you notice anything?

Comment: It is better without logarithms. Play around with the calculator. Make a table. You will remain in much better control than if you throw it into the log machine.

Comment: Okay, I think I did this right through guess and check. 

Say population = p |
Let p = 2000 |

p(1.25)^n

So:
10 years = p(1.25)^1
20 years = p(1.25)^2
30 years = p(1.25)^3
40 years = p(1.25)^4
50 years = p(1.25)^5

Therefore:
A) The population will double after ≈ 30 years since 2000(1.25)^3 = 3906
B) The population will triple ≈ 50 years since 2000(1.25)^5 = 6103.5

Is this valid?

Comment: Very close. Your formula is exactly right, however I think your answer could be a little more precise and accurate. At 30 years, you get that the population went from 2000 to 3906, which isn't quite double. How could you see what the population is at 31, 32, 33 years? You the first year that the population is more that 4000. Then do the same thing with 50 years, only working the other way (since 6103.5 is bigger than 6000). So you'd try 49, 48, 47... again looking for the first year that the population was bigger than 6000.

Comment: Okay, so roughly something along the lines of: $2000(1.25)^3.1=3994.4 ≈ 4000$ and $2000(1.25)^4.93 = 6008.9 ≈ 6000.$

Comment: I assume you mean $2000(1.25)^{3.1}$ and $2000(1.25)^{4.93}$ (writing latex can be tricky). 3994 still isn't quite 4000, so you'd probably use 3.2 (which will be 32 years). and since you want to use full years, your answer for B) should be 50 years.

Comment: 3.11 is 4003, so to the closest year since you can't round down years I am assuming round up to 3.2 and 49.3 rounds to 50. Question = complete? Thank's alot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to come up with a formula for the change in the population after $n$ years, and then try and figure out what whole number you have to plug in to $n$ so the change is atleast 2, and then atleast 3.

EDIT: the $A(t)=A_0*(1-r)^{t/p}$ is very similar to what you will have to use, but that is for  some value that is decreasing by $r$ every $p$ years. So if the population of the city was decreasing by $\frac{1}{3}$ you would get a formula of $A(t)=A_0 \cdot (1-\frac {1}{3})^{t/10}=A_0 \cdot (\frac {2}{3})^{t/10}$. Can you modify that, or find the right formula, when the population is increasing?

Comment: So because we are already given the $(1-r)$, the formula can be written simply as A(1.25)^t/10?

I wrote what I think is the solution a few minutes ago: Say population = p | Let p = 2000 | $p(1.25)^n$ So: 10 years = p(1.25)^1 20 years = p(1.25)^2 30 years = p(1.25)^3 40 years = p(1.25)^4 50 years = p(1.25)^5 Therefore: A) The population will double after ≈ 30 years since 2000(1.25)^3 = 3906 B) The population will triple ≈ 50 years since $2000(1.25)^5 = 6103.5 $Is this valid?

Comment: That formula is exactly right. However, I would try to narrow down your answer a bit. You know that 30 is really close to the answer (since it is almost, but not quite double), so you can try 31, 32, 32... until you find the first year where the population is more than 4000. Then do the same thing for 50 years, looking for the first year where the population is above 6000. Only this time you'd want to work backwards (49, 48, 47...)

Answer (score 0):

Given the formula for a geometric sequence: $\{a_n\} = a_1 * r^{n}$, you can find an equation for it. Let $r = \frac54$ and call $n$ $x$ and $a_1$ is the initial population. You get: $$A = a_1*\left(\frac54\right)^{x}$$ where $x$ is the number of years passed (multiplies $a_1$ by $\frac54$ each year). To find $x$ when $A = 2a_1$: $$2a_1=a_1*\left(\frac54\right)^x$$$$2=\left(\frac54\right)^x$$ test the equation for $x = {1,2,3,4}$ (multiply $\frac54$ by itself ${1,2,3,4}$ times) and you will see that $3<x<4$ so the answer is $4$ because you are asked to find an integer amount of years. If you want to solve for the exact answer, you do have to use a logarithm:$$\log_{\frac54}2=x$$$$\frac{\log_{10}2}{\log_{10}{\frac54}} = x$$$$x\approx3.1$$